# WinForms Target Framework 4.6.1 but it's running as 4.0

Tags: .net, winforms

Why isn't .NET 4.6.1. being used?

When I create a brand new, out of the box WinForms project and specify that I want it to target the .NET 4.6.1 framework, it reports that it actually running under 4.0.3 ??

I verified this by simply adding a label for Form1 and set it to this value:
Label1.Text = ".NET version: " + System.Environment.Version.ToString()

It's reporting .NET version: 4.0.30319.42000

I want to upgrade my app from .net 4.0 to .net 4.6.1 but it doesn't want to use .net 4.6.1 for some reason.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?  I thought it was something in my application, but it happens when you create a new out of the box WinForms application as well.

Comment: I got it.  System.Environment.Version shows .NET 4.0 because that's the version of the CLR, but this statement returns the latest version installed.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(GetType(Integer).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion

Comment: Or for C#:  System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(int).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion

Answer (score 0):

I got it. System.Environment.Version shows .NET 4.0 because that's the version of the CLR, but this statement returns the latest version installed.

VB.NET:  System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(GetType(Integer).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion

C#: System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(int).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion